# Explain results of K-means

Tags: algorithm, attributes, instance, cluster-analysis, classification

I make some predictions using classifiers and clusters in Weka.I know how to analyze the results of classifiers but i don't know what some results of clusters like K-means really mean.I know that clusters work different.To be more clear i want to specifically explain the full meaning of the table under the // comments:

EDIT:I make predictions based on one of the attributes.Do the 3 clusters generated in the table correspond to the 3 answers that, that attribute has, or the 3 clusters are something more random?Can i really use clustering to make predictions?

```
kMeans  
======

Number of iterations: 9
Within cluster sum of squared errors: 297.46622082142716
Missing values globally replaced with mean/mode

Cluster centroids:
                            Cluster# 
Attribute        Full Data         0         1         2
                     (477)     (136)     (172)     (169)
 =======================================================
Religion            8.6939    7.6691    8.9709    9.2367
Vote_Criterion      2.7736    2.8971    2.4942    2.9586
Sex                 1.4906    1.4559         2         1
DateBirth        1930.7652 1937.5147 1920.2965 1935.9882
Educ                3.2201    3.2721    3.2209    3.1775
Immigrant           1.6415    1.6838    1.5872    1.6627 
Income              2.4675       2.5    2.5523     2.355
Occupation          3.6184    3.8162    3.2907    3.7929
Vote2013                 1         2         1         1




 Time taken to build model (full training data) : 0.06 seconds

=== Model and evaluation on training set ===


   //PLEASE EXPLAIN THE FOLLOWING TABLE
    Clustered Instances

    0       136 ( 29%)
    1      172 ( 36%)
    2      169 ( 35%)
```

EDIT2:The vote2013 is a vote intention attribute that has 3 values,1,2 and 3 for 3 candidate presidents.So,what are 1,2 in vote2013 mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of  **failed k-means**.

And it's actually not the algorithms fault, but you are using it on **data that is inappropriate for k-means**. Let me explain what "clusters" k-means found for you:

Cluster #0 is the users that voted in 2013 (assuming that `2` means they voted?)

Of the remaining instances, Cluster #1 is `sex 2` (females?) and Cluster #2 is `sex 1` (males?).

The problem is that k-means minimizes variance. And splitting the data on binary attributes such as "sex" and "voted" yields a massive improvement with respect to decreasing the variance. But it doesn't actually yield any useful information!

**Don't use k-means on discrete attributes, EVER.** It optimizes a mathematical measure - sum of squares - which only makes sense on *continuous* variables.

Comment: I agree that k-means has split the data by Sex and Vote2013 but one thing puzzles me - how as the split found Vote2013 = 1 and 2 while the total for Vote2013 = 1? The case of Sex, where the total reflects a mixture of the two, makes more sense. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: The vote2013 is a vote intention attribute that has 3 values,1,2 and 3 for 3 candidate presidents.So,what are 1,2 in vote2013 mean?(from EDIT2)

Comment: Just a guess: maybe, because it's a class attribute, it gets treated differently. Instead of giving the mean, the majority class is reported?

Answer (score 0):

```
//PLEASE EXPLAIN THE FOLLOWING TABLE
Clustered Instances

0       136 ( 29%)
1      172 ( 36%)
2      169 ( 35%)
```

Three clusters were identified, 0, 1 and 2.

1. The first cluster contained 136 data points, which is 29% of the total of 477 data points.
2. The second cluster contained 172 data points, which is 36% of the total of 477 data points.
3. The third cluster contained 169 data points, which is 35% of the total of 477 data points.

This seems easy enough - did I misunderstand your problem?

**EDIT**
The output you posted just shows the clusters that were identified using k-means. You have three clusters with the centroids given by the combination of attributes shown in the first table.

I'm not sure what you mean by *"I make predictions based on one of the attributes"* - this algorithm will allow you to take an unknown sample (with all attributes) and to identify which cluster it's nearest to. That actually means very little outside of the context of your data. The k-means algorithm will give a different number of clusters at different levels of granularity, so it's really a tool for identifying relationships that exist in the data but that are hard to derive by inspection.

If you were using it for classification, you would first identify clusters, then assign each cluster a classification, then you can classify incoming samples by finding the closest cluster centroid.